# What does the parameter in my condition means?

Tags: perl, if-statement, parameters

I have a script written like this:

```
if (!(-e "ARGV[0]"))
{
     printf("\nThis file \"%s\" does not exist.\n\n", $ARGV[0]);
     exit;
}
```

What does the parameter "-e" mean in my condition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`-e`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) means "does a file exist". Your code checks for a file named `"ARGV[0]"`, if that files does not exist it prints to the console. However, I think you have made a mistake and want to check for files passed in from the command line?

If so, change `if (!(-e "ARGV[0]"))` to `if (!(-e $ARGV[0]))`. This means if the file specified in `$ARGV[0]` does not exist, print an error. [`@ARGV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#@ARGV) means things passed in from the command line - so if you ran `perl myscript.pl hello.txt new.txt`, `$ARGV[0]` would be `hello.txt`, and `$ARGV[1]` would be `new.txt`.

So this code prints an error if a non-exisiting file is passed in as argument 0 from the command line, so `hello.txt` does not exist.

```
if (!(-e $ARGV[0]))
{ 
     printf("\nThis file \"%s\" does not exist.\n\n", $ARGV[0]);
     exit;
}
else{
     printf("That file exists!");
}
```

I apologise if you are indeed checking for the existence of a file named `"ARGV[0]"`.